# jmod: "Error: module-info.class not found" despite it existing in the jar file

Tags: java, java-module, jmod

Attempting to create a .mod file from a jar file.

```bash
 $JAVA_HOME/bin/jmod create --class-path ./bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on-171.jar bouncycastle.mod
```

results in:

```
Error: module-info.class not found
java.io.IOException: module-info.class not found
    at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jmod.JmodTask$JmodFileWriter.writeModuleInfo(JmodTask.java:538)
    at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jmod.JmodTask$JmodFileWriter.write(JmodTask.java:476)
    at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jmod.JmodTask.create(JmodTask.java:433)
    at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jmod.JmodTask.run(JmodTask.java:208)
    at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jmod.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

that classfile does exist though, and it is [valid](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/main/jdk1.9/module-info.java)

```bash
jar -tvf bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on-171.jar | grep module

  7672 Thu Mar 31 10:06:58 PDT 2022 META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does `jar -d -f bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on-171.jar` display any module information?

Comment: @VGR yes, but only if I add `--release 9` to the jar command.  `jar  -d  -f bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on-171.jar --release 9`

Comment: Does the manifest of bcprov-jdk18on-171.jar contain a `Multi-Release: true` line?

Comment: yes, `Multi-Release: true` is present

Comment: what if you change the command to use `--module-path ./bouncycastle` instead of the classpath, does that help?